# Reorder model objects in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have several configuration objects in `django` admin panel.
They are listed in the following order

- Email config
- General config
- Network config

Each object can be configured separately, but all of them are included in `General config`. So basically you will need mostly `General config`, so I want to move it to the top.
I know how to order fields in a model itself, but how to reorder models?

Comment: I don't see an obvious solution to this — the models are sorted by their `_meta.verbose_name_plural`, and this happens inside the `AdminSite.index` view, with no obvious place to hook custom code, short of subclassing the `AdminSite` class and providing your own `index` method, which is however a huge monolithic method, _very_ inheritance-unfriendly.

Comment: OK :( Could you please write an answer that it's not a reasonable thing to do, so I can close the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see an obvious solution to this — the models are sorted by their _meta.verbose_name_plural, and this happens inside the AdminSite.index view, with no obvious place to hook custom code, short of subclassing the AdminSite class and providing your own index method, which is however a huge monolithic method, very inheritance-unfriendly.

Comment: So I've just wrote a django package that will allow you reorder django app list/ rename app label and model names (including 3rd party apps) — you can download it from here:

https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder

Answer (score 12):

So I've just wrote a django package that will allow you reorder django app list/ rename app label and model names (including 3rd party apps) — you can download it from here:

https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder

Comment: Recently i used it and found an issue. Although the package works well in the index page, in all other pages the model orders are being shown as regular (default, provided by django). Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind using a dirty trick, prepend `verbose_name_plural` of your models with a certain number of invisible [zero-width spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm). E.g. prepend "Email config" with 1 zero-width space, "General config" with 2 and "Network config" with 3. This is really the simplest method and I've yet to find any shortcomings.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this snippet for reordering models in the django admin panel](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1939/) - it works for us (though check out the comments below the snippet for updates to make it work with Django >= 1.4)

And for the longer term there is this [django bug report about the ordering of models within apps](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7497).  The bug report is open at the time of writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reorder your apps (tested with `Django 1.11.10`).

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}

        # Move last app to the top of `app_list`.
        app_list = self.get_app_list(request)
        app_list.insert(0, app_list.pop(-1))

        extra_context['app_list'] = app_list
        return super().index(request, extra_context)
```